# Problem with building unity project and exporting to ios project

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, prefab

I'm not a unity specialist, I'm doing ios development. But I need to build and export the unity model to my project. In the unit itself, I see a mozhel, it is animated, that is, everything seems to work, but when exporting, I get the following errors. Tell me what you need to do for a successful export, thanks in advance!

Problem detected while opening the Scene file: 'Assets/Scenes/debug.unity'.
Check the following logs for more details.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Prefab instance problem: '1 (Missing Prefab with guid: d7cbffd902e3d0d45b47336e071f6d89)'. Missing Prefab asset with guid d7cbffd902e3d0d45b47336e071f6d89.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Prefab instance problem: 'Merge_2_f (Missing Prefab with guid: eaacf97144b803044a1ddd707eef1149)'. Missing Prefab asset with guid eaacf97144b803044a1ddd707eef1149.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

BuildFailedException: Burst compiler (1.7.4) failed running

stdout:
Failed to determine xcode installation path - "xcode-select -p" is XCode installed?  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

stderr:

Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.4/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1468)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.4/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1334)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler+BclRunner.RunManagedProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.4/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:1309)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLsImpl (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.4/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:557)
Unity.Burst.Editor.BurstAotCompiler.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.burst@1.7.4/Editor/BurstAotCompiler.cs:208)
UnityEditor.Build.BuildPipelineInterfaces.OnPostBuildPlayerScriptDLLs (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildPipelineInterfaces.cs:541)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

Error building Player: 5 errors

Error building Player: 7 errors

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2507 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

```
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 9 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ce] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:193 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/build/output/unity/unity/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)
```

Comment: Did you check Include dependencies option when exporting?

Answer (score 0):

The first errors suggest to me that you inserted prefabs in your scene and later removed them in your assets.
Take a closer look at this. In the Inspector these should be marked in red.

As far as I know, you can only build for iOS if you are on one of these devices yourself. If you are not, I assume that you cannot build it.